# What does "afeard" mean?

Tags: archaic-language

> Too much afeard to die

Would you tell me what this archaic phrase means?

Comment: The only archaic word in there is _afeard_, which [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=afeard) immediately tells me means _afraid). The other words seem quite common. What exactly is unclear about **too much afraid to die**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Too much afeard to die - simply means too much afraid to die

Such words can be easily found on the Internet and a little homework from our side would be helpful. :)

Here it is...

> [afeard (adj)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=afeard%20) - *A pronunciation of afraid*. You may also say 'fraid though it is *non-standard*.

The Wikipedia has the [whole page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afeard) about it. It redirects if you type that term.

Comment: *Such words can be easily found on the Internet* Then why didn't you vote to close instead? Answering the question encourages future posters (or the same poster, in future) to ask questions without doing any research first.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I could not understand it's definition, although I have searched enough.

Comment: Thank you so much all. I got the whole lessons which you have provided me.

Comment: @nima_persian If you've found a definition that you can't understand it's a good idea to include it in the question. This shows that you've tried to do your own research and got stuck, which is fine. Without that information it looks like you're trying to use ELL as a dictionary, which is not fine.

Comment: @starsplusplus you just pasted it half! The full sentence is ... "Such words can be easily found on the Internet **and a little homework from our side would be helpful."** I answered as Nima frequently asks questions and many of them are useful. On the other hand, I told her that such questions are to be self evaluated first!

Comment: @MaulikV To be honest, I didn't really understand that part of your sentence. I assumed you meant that homework from *her* side would be helpful. Saying "but" instead of "and" would have made your meaning clearer, I think. Ah well, at least we understand each other now.

Comment: @nima_persian What Nigel said. People can also give you a better answer if you explain WHY you didn't understand the definition. If you don't tell them that, they might just post the same definition you found already!